# Want to change path for linked table in ms access 2000

Tags: ms-access, linked-tables

I have an MS Access database which is already linked with many tables in Oracle.
I want to add few more tables to that from different server of Oracle.

The problem is if I connect to the server through MS Access and try to import using linked table manager I *could not find my schema or user in that list of tables*.

This Link tables dialog even from *Get External data->Link Tables* gives me only system tables like (CTXSYS,DMSYS,XDB etc....).

Why can I not find any of my tables? Do I not have access to this?

How do I achieve this? Why are my table schema's not listed even if I connect to the right server?

Comment: oh!. i will post in that too. i need some help regd this. i thot this could be solved by programming things.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recall how the Linked Table Manager worked in Access 2000, so I may be off base here.  However, in Access 2003, the Linked Table Manager allows me to change the connections for existing table links, but doesn't provide an option to create new links.  (at least not an option I can find)

IOW, if the same source table existed on a different server, I could use the Linked Table Manager to change an existing link for that table to point to the new server.  But, with no existing link to the source table, I can't use the Linked Table Manager to create one.

For that purpose, I go to Access' main menu and choose File -> Get External Data -> Link Tables, choose "ODBC Databases()" from the "Files of Type" box on the Link dialog, then choose the DSN for the server which houses the tables I want linked.  IIRC, you should have a similar option with Access 2000.

You could also use VBA code to create your links.  See [TransferDatabase Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa193063%28office.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks HansUp. But i tried Get External Data-> Link Tables too. but its also not working for me. i could not find my user/ schema tables alone...

Comment: HansUp do you guess what kind of problem is this??

Comment: You may have stumped me then.  I haven't used ODBC links to Oracle in a few years, but I recalled it as similar to ODBC links to SQL Server or PostGreSQL which both work fine for me from Access.  Best I can suggest is to double-ckeck the properties of your DSN for the Oracle server.  Perhaps you can find something from the Oracle side to explain why it's not showing you want you expect.

Comment: sorry Hansup i didnt mean to be hard. its all are correct anyways i ll check it again and let you know

Comment: Check with your Oracle DBA to see if she can tell you what's happening with your ODBC connections.  Seems like you would get an error message if your connection is using the wrong user credentials.  So maybe that user doesn't have access to the schema objects you expect.

Comment: And another long shot ... there are different ODBC drivers for Oracle.  Microsoft provides one; and Oracle provides another.  Maybe switching drivers will fix this.

Comment: HansUp i found out that this link table provides me only list of SYSTABLES. (CTXSYS,DMSYS,MDSYS etc).... but i could not find any user tables?

Comment: Your symptoms sound to me like the schema doesn't include user tables.  Whether or not that is true, I don't think this is a MS Access issue.  My best guess is you need to resolve this on the Oracle side, and I can't help you there.

Comment: ok thanks HansUp. let me check with Oracle DBA team too... thanks for guidence